# Cancel a request using jquery.Ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I am currently setting up a projects page with a series of links to project images, these images are loaded in using jquery load at the moment. However if I click a link then click a different link in quick succession it seems to load the images from the first link rather than cancelling that request and loading the second link

I gather from what I have been reading that the best method use would be to swap jquery load for jquery Ajax, the only issue is that I don't quite understand how to achieve this with jquery ajax, I would be grateful if someone could give me a starting point

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming right now, you're calling something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').load('projects.php?page=1');
```

The exact equivalent using *ajax()* would be:

```
$.ajax('projects.php?page=1', {
  success: function(html) {
    $('#mydiv').html(html);
  }
});
```

I'm guessing people told you that you would want to abort the old request and start a new one? You can do that by saving the jqXHR object returned by *ajax()* and using it later:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax('first url', ...);

// Later
jqXHR.abort();
var jqXHR = $.ajax('second url', ...);
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started, let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to read: [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery) They explain that very thing.  For some reason, StackOverflow wants to convert this to a comment, not an answer, so I've added this sentence.